# How to iterate through each probability column of a dataframe and find the row number from where the probability goes below 50% in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

I have a dataframe which is the output of predict_survival_function() from cox propotional model, which gives the probability of survival of customers for every month (index row number) and in columns we have the customers. So I would like to get the month number for each customers when the probability goes below 0.50. Below is the screenshot of the table.

[image]

The output I am looking for is something like below -
Suppose for first customer **No. 4 (First column in the dataframe)** If the probability goes less than 0.50 at row number 55. Then the output should be

[image]

And similar for all the other columns in the data frame.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: And you avoid writing actual loops to do so because you deem it to be unpythonic?

Comment: I wanted to avoid loops because I have millions of customers to iterate through, which might be very time consuming. @Aziuth

Comment: Doesn't the accepted solution do that behind the scene? You'd probably need to implement something like a binary search like algorithm if time is of the essence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
>>> df
          4         5         7
0  0.974789  0.976546  0.913151
1  0.918408  0.815823  0.909577
2  0.748928  0.801727  0.856562
3  0.691171  0.791815  0.794988
4  0.442441  0.669530  0.750395  # Customer 4, first value below 0.5 -> row 4
5  0.378585  0.568831  0.561721
6  0.285419  0.287814  0.521966  # Customer 5, first value below 0.5 -> row 6
7  0.240335  0.216207  0.176980  # Customer 7, first value below 0.5 -> row 7
8  0.191656  0.095793  0.118300
9  0.183290  0.087297  0.035063
```

IIUC, you can use `idxmax`:

```
>>> (df <= 0.5).idxmax()
4    4
5    6
7    7
dtype: int64
```

Full output:

```
out = ((df <= 0.5).idxmax().rename_axis('Customer Number')
                  .rename('Row Number').reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
   Customer Number  Row Number
0                4           4
1                5           6
2                7           7
```